# java.net.ProtocolException: unexpected end of stream when uploading file by Rx2AndroidNetworking

Tags: rx-java2, rx-android, multipart, android-networking, multifile-uploader

I got that error when uploading a file to the server 
java.net.ProtocolException: unexpected end of stream when uploading file by

```
Rx2AndroidNetworking.upload(serverUrl)
                .addMultipartFile("file", mFile)
                .addQueryParameter("fileName", fileName)
                .build()
                .setUploadProgressListener(iFileUploadActions)
                .getObjectObservable(Response.class);
```

Answer (score 3):

Double check your source code if it has these lines below, please remove those:

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        AndroidNetworking.enableLogging(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    }
```

OR change to:

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        AndroidNetworking.enableLogging(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC);
    }
```

Comment: LifeSaver. But can you please add a little bit of explanation?